# Passar array de imagens no FormData()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso adicionar um *array* de imagens no `FormData`, mas somente a primeira imagem está passando.

Sei que o problema está no código *JS* por que quando envio o formulário direto para a página *php*, funciona normal.

*JavaScript*

```
var url = $(this).attr('action');
var dados = new FormData();

$.each($("input[type='file']")[0].files, function(i, file) {
    dados.append('imagem[]', file);
});

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: dados,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<label for="1">Imagem 1</label>
<input type="file" name="imagem[]" id="1"/>

<label for="1">Imagem 2</label>
<input type="file" name="imagem[]" id="2" />

<label for="1">Imagem 3</label>
<input type="file" name="imagem[]" id="3" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quiser enviar todos os campos (possíveis) do formulário, basta utilizar:

```
let dados = new FormData(this);
```

Caso você queira enviar, apenas, alguns dados, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
let formData = new FormData();

$(this).find('input:file').each(function(index, element) {
    formData.append( 'imagem[]', element.files[0] )
});
```